# Signed Java applet - "Your security settings have blocked an untrusted application from running"

Tags: java, security, applet, signed

I have done the following:
1. Compiled an applet in Netbeans

1. Set the manifest content to...

   Application-Name: MyApp

   Permissions: all-permissions

   Manifest-Version: 1.0

   Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.8.4

   Created-By: 1.7.0_21-b11 (Oracle Corporation)
2. Signed the jar with a Comodo certificate.
3. Verified the jar
4. Set my HTML code as...

> < applet code="myapp.Test.class" archive="MyApp.jar" width="500"
>   height="300" />
>         < param name="background" value="FF9900" />
>
> ```
>   < param name="foreground" value="000000" />
>
>   < param name="buttoncolour" value="FF9900" />
>
>   < param name="winbackground" value="CCCCFF" />
>
>   < param name="messagecolour" value="FF33FF" />
>
>   < param name="fontsize" value="13" />
>
>   < param name="fontstyle" value="PLAIN" />
>
>   < param name="fontface" value="Arial" />
>
> < / applet >
> ```

But when I try and run the applet in IE or FF, I get the message "Your security settings have blocked an untrusted application from running".

I've tried adding "Trusted-Library: true" and "Trusted-Only: true" to the manifest but that just gives me a different error. And I've also tried "Permissions: sandbox" - with many variations of all these attributes.

Not sure where I'm going wrong. Can anyone help? Thanks.

Comment: 7u21? That's a little bit out of date. `Trusted-Library` should only be used if you **really** know what you're doing.

Comment: Clearly, I didn't *really* know what I was doing - hence the question. +1 for you, though, for looking smarter than me...

Comment: I seriously mean it. Writing trustable libraries is absurdly difficult. (Retaliation downvoting isn't cool whoever it is. Haven't downvoted this question, but I think it adds value and should be deleted.)

Comment: Thank you for your help. Incidentally, I tried the Trusted-Library attribute as I saw it as a suggested solution elsewhere, so mentioned it as one of the things I had already tried.

Answer (score 0):

My bad. The problem was that I was signing the wrong applet. All running fine now.